# Keycloak Starting with separate DB_SCHEMA an error occured

Tags: keycloak

we are trying to run keycloak using postgres db as database in separate schema `keycloak_schema` an error has occured.

```
02:53:07,349 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Database info: {databaseUrl=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak_dashbord_db, databaseUser=fc_db_user, databaseProduct=PostgreSQL 13.2, databaseDriver=PostgreSQL JDBC Driver 42.2.5}
02:53:12,475 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Initializing database schema. Using changelog META-INF/jpa-changelog-master.xml

02:53:29,181 ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Change Set META-INF/jpa-changelog-13.0.0.xml::json-string-accomodation::keycloak failed.  Error: ERROR: relation "realm_attribute" does not exist
  Position: 8 [Failed SQL: UPDATE REALM_ATTRIBUTE SET VALUE_NEW = VALUE, VALUE = NULL]
02:53:29,181 ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Error has occurred while updating the database: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-13.0.0.xml::json-string-accomodation::keycloak:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "realm_attribute" does not exist
  Position: 8 [Failed SQL: UPDATE REALM_ATTRIBUTE SET VALUE_NEW = VALUE, VALUE = NULL]
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:619)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:188)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.updateChangeSet(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:184)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:103)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:82)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory$2.run(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:354)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:250)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.update(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:347)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.migration(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:319)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lambda$lazyInit$0(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:183)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:771)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lazyInit(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:134)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:82)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:60)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:315)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:63)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:39)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:315)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.realmLocalStorage(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:227)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getRealmDelegate(RealmCacheSession.java:149)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getRealm(RealmCacheSession.java:411)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.managers.ApplianceBootstrap.isNewInstall(ApplianceBootstrap.java:46)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$2.run(KeycloakApplication.java:180)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:250)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.bootstrap(KeycloakApplication.java:155)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:124)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@13.0.0//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:36)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2835)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:376)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:288)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:98)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:140)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "realm_attribute" does not exist
  Position: 8 [Failed SQL: UPDATE REALM_ATTRIBUTE SET VALUE_NEW = VALUE, VALUE = NULL]
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:309)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:113)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1277)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1259)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:582)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "realm_attribute" does not exist
  Position: 8
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.27.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.execute(WrappedStatement.java:198)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:307)
    ... 72 more

02:53:29,199 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to update database
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:118)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:82)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory$2.run(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:354)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:250)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.update(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:347)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.migration(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:319)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lambda$lazyInit$0(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:183)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:771)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.lazyInit(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:134)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:82)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.create(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:60)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:315)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:63)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.jpa.JpaRealmProviderFactory.create(JpaRealmProviderFactory.java:39)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.getProvider(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:315)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSession.realmLocalStorage(DefaultKeycloakSession.java:227)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getRealmDelegate(RealmCacheSession.java:149)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-infinispan@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.RealmCacheSession.getRealm(RealmCacheSession.java:411)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.managers.ApplianceBootstrap.isNewInstall(ApplianceBootstrap.java:46)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$2.run(KeycloakApplication.java:180)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@13.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:250)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.bootstrap(KeycloakApplication.java:155)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:124)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@13.0.0//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:36)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@13.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:112)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2835)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:376)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:288)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:98)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:140)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:588)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:559)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:601)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@23.0.2.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set META-INF/jpa-changelog-13.0.0.xml::json-string-accomodation::keycloak:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "realm_attribute" does not exist
  Position: 8 [Failed SQL: UPDATE REALM_ATTRIBUTE SET VALUE_NEW = VALUE, VALUE = NULL]
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:619)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:188)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.updateChangeSet(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:184)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@13.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.update(LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider.java:103)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "realm_attribute" does not exist
  Position: 8 [Failed SQL: UPDATE REALM_ATTRIBUTE SET VALUE_NEW = VALUE, VALUE = NULL]
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:309)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:55)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:113)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1277)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1259)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:582)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "realm_attribute" does not exist
  Position: 8
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.27.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.execute(WrappedStatement.java:198)
    at org.liquibase//liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:307)
    ... 72 more
```

Postgres container is loaded with initial script to create schema and keycloak tables are generated in schema specified.

> docker-compose file

```
    keycloak:
        container_name: keycloak_demo
        image: jboss/keycloak:13.0.0
        environment:
            DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
            DB_ADDR: postgres
            DB_SCHEMA: keycloak_schema
            DB_DATABASE: keycloak_dashbord_db
            DB_USER: db_user
            DB_PASSWORD: db_pass
            KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/'
            KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
            KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
        ports: 
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        networks: 
            - keycloak-dev-net
    postgres:
        container_name: keycloak_postgres
        image: postgres:13-alpine
        volumes:
            - keycloak_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - ./create_schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_schema.sql
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: keycloak_db
            POSTGRES_USER: db_user
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: db_pass
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        networks:
            - keycloak-dev-net
```

[Error Log](https://gist.github.com/jithset/ed6bea225654e3416e6d7e441a5bcc23)

Comment: Working with public postgres schema verified

Comment: I have the same error. I checked the db table REALM_ATTRIBUTE and there are only the columns NAME, READLM_ID and VALUE. Not sure what liquibase tries with "Failed SQL: UPDATE REALM_ATTRIBUTE SET VALUE_NEW = VALUE, VALUE = NULL"
In my case the error showd up after I updated the JDBC Connect String and enabled some metrics. I´ll roll that back to see if there is a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the new 13.0.1 version of keycloak?

https://www.keycloak.org/2021/05/keycloak-1301-released

The Version includes a fix for the issue

```
Update to 13.0.0 fails due to liquibase error for non-default schema
```

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-18239?jql=project%20%3D%20keycloak%20and%20fixVersion%20%3D%2013.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and found a solution for it. In version 13.0.0, there is a bug as the commentator wrote above. It is necessary for the user to specify the scheme as default.

```
ALTER ROLE {user} SET search_path = {scheme name}
```